# Wordpress / CSS File only for one Menu-Page in the Backend

Tags: css, wordpress, if-statement

I have a own Plugin and I want to add a css file to style the menu-page for this plugin in the backend. Right now the css file works for all pages in the backend but it should only works for my plugin.

```
function ww_contact_backend_style() {
wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', '/wp-content/plugins/ww- contact/css/backend.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ww_contact_backend_style');
```

I tried this, but it didn´t work:

```
if(menu_page_url('ww_options')){}
```

Comment: do you mean you want to add css only for that plugin menu page?

Comment: @charankumar yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example: Load CSS File from a plugin on specific Admin Page**

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        // Load only on ?page=mypluginname
        if($hook != 'toplevel_page_mypluginname') {
                return;
        }
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

[See wp doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)